# Image is getting blury when Zooming In

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimage, zooming

I am trying to zoom to a image in my view. For that I used `UIScrollView` and in that scrollView I placed a ImageView. I had set min and max zoom scale of scrollview.

I used this code too..

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return imgView;
}
```

The problem is My image gets blury while zoomig. Any one have idea how to redraw image with the zoom size.

Comment: Just to check, how big (in pixels) is your scrollview and how big (in pixels) is the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi set maximumZoomScale=1.0f. it wont blurr :)

Comment: in this case it won't get zoom... My min scale is 1.0. I want to enlarge Image... Is there any way to redraw the image..?

Comment: just scale down ur minimumScale level to ur screenSize. if you use maximumScale more than 1 then it will blurr your image :)

Comment: So there is no way to use scale more then 1? Actully I had done this using draw rect method in UIView class while working on PDF drawing. Is it possible with Images..?

Comment: A scale of 1 is "1:1" or "realsize" - it's the actual resolution of the image.  If you scale larger than 1, then you are enlarging the image to bigger than it is which results in the bluring as it has to "guess" to fill in the pixels to enlarge it.